# Is it possible to have a constant of the literal type inside the type

Tags: c++, c++20

Say, I have a class like follows:

```cpp
class LiteralType {
  public:
    constexpr LiteralType(size_t v): v_(v) {}

    std::string tag() const {
      std::ostringstream os;
      os << v_;
      return os.str();
    }

    constexpr size_t doubled() const {
      return v_ * 2;
    }

  private:
    size_t v_;
};
```

How can I introduce a constant that is a class static field. E.g. I want a constant that would be accessible as `LiteralType::kFive` and used in contexts like `std::array<size_t, LiteralType::kFive.doubled()>`.

I can do a standalone constant, but my actual class is a template class so I would rather have it inside the class.

### Update:

Realized I can do a static function:

```cpp
static constexpr LiteralType five() {
    return {5};
}
```

Still, would prefer a constant.

Comment: `LiteralType` can't have a `static` data member of type `LiteralType`, since `LiteralType` is an incomplete type in that context.

Comment: `inline constexpr LiteralType five{5};` _after_ the class definition may be an option.

Comment: @TedLyngmo true, but then it's not a class member, so can't be referred to as `LiteralType::five`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, but perhaps it could be put in a namespace to give the same "feeling" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You just have to split the constant up:

```cpp
class LiteralType {
public:
    constexpr LiteralType(size_t v): v_(v) {}

    // declaration in here
    static const LiteralType five;
private:
    size_t v_;
};

// definition out here
inline constexpr LiteralType LiteralType::five(5);
```

This is the same mechanism by which, for instance, `std::strong_ordering::equal` is an object of type `std::strong_ordering`.